# How can I CDI inject an EJB in Glassfish 3.1.2.2 and make it serializable?

Tags: java, glassfish, ejb, cdi

In Glassfish  3.1.2.2 (build 5), when I inject an EJB using @Inject instead of @EJB (I declare it transient), I'm not able to serialize than bean. If I change to @EJB it will work.

```
@Inject
transient BDEJB ejb;
```

I don´t have the same problem with WebSphere.

It's important for me to use CDI to inject alternatives for testing.

It's important for me to ensure that session scoped beans are serializable in order to ensure session cluster works

```
package com.gneis.explains.ejb;

import java.util.List;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

import com.gneis.explains.jpa.BaseDatos;

@Stateless
@Named
public class BDEJB {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "ORARQU")
    protected EntityManager em;

    public List<BaseDatos> getBasesDeDatos() {
        return em.createQuery("select bd from BaseDatos bd").getResultList();
    }

    public void add(BaseDatos bd) {
        em.persist(bd);
    }

    public void delete(BaseDatos bd) {
        em.remove(em.find(BaseDatos.class, bd.getId()));
    }

    public void update(BaseDatos bd) {
        em.merge(bd);
    }

}
```

Comment: https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-15225 check out not sure but seemed like a bug to me.

Comment: Where did you get GlassFish 3.5?

Comment: Sorry. I've edited the question. It's  3.1.2.2 (build 5)

Comment: is BDEJB interface is simple? does it extends other interfaces?

Comment: It's a simple CRUD. I've edited the question to include de code

Comment: Can you try to make an interface out of that class, and inject an interface. It could be that CDI injects an object not a proxy, it is required to have an interface to proxy objects in CDI

Comment: Actually your EJB is Stateless, what is the point to serialize it?

Comment: I don´t want to serialize an EJB. I want to be sure that session clusters work. In order to get that I need everything in session to be serializable. For some reason Glassfish puts this injected EJBs in session, so I becomes non serializable. The point is that with many developers, if I don´t make something automatic, some one will break session serialization capability